# 'perf_event_open' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, perf

When I execute the code below the compiler tells me error: ‘perf_event_open’ was not declared in this scope;

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/hw_breakpoint.h>
#include <linux/perf_event.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  struct perf_event_attr pe;
  memset(&pe, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
  pe.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
  pe.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
  pe.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES;
  pe.disabled = 1;
  pe.exclude_kernel = 1;
  pe.exclude_hv = 1;

  int fd = perf_event_open(&pe, 0, -1, -1, 0);
  if (fd == -1) {
    std::cerr << "Error opening perf event\n";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
  ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);

  sleep(1);

  ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, 0);
  long long cnt;
  read(fd, &cnt, sizeof(long long));

  std::cout << "CPU Cycles: " << cnt << std::endl;
  close(fd);
  return 0;
}
```

And the "**/proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid**" file exists in my machine.
Why is that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you read [the `perf_event_open` manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html) you will see that it says "Note: glibc provides no wrapper for `perf_event_open()`, necessitating the use of `syscall(2)`". In short, there's just no such function declared anywhere, like the errors is saying. Today's lesson: Always read available documentation.